# Accessing a pages events using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-2

Just started working with the Facebook graph api and have hit abit of a wall.  I want to access facebook pages by using the api /events/ however i have discovered that this requires an access token, IE a login. (at least thats how i think works)

Basically my site lists bands and events, so id like the user (band) to specify a connection to their facebook page if they have one (pageId) so i can dynamically pull the events they have posted to their facebook page.

Is this even at all possible?  at the moment i am able to pull in the pages feed like /feed/ but running /events/ throws an excpetion saying it requires an access token.

Im using PHP with a fresh install of codeigniter 2.0 its also worth mentioning im using elliot haughins facebook library [facebook library](http://www.haughin.com/2011/02/08/brand-new-facebook-codeigniter-library-released/) though this isnt essential to my project

Answer (score 1):

You can register an app with facebook and it can have it's own token that you can use to access the event for pages.  You can find out how to get an app token here. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Hope that helps.